# LP Model - Using Solver

Tags: excel, solver

Can anyone help me creating the requirements for LP Solver for below scenario please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpFz1.png)
Requirements:
The chocolate in your overall feed plan (in pounds) cannot exceed the amount of nonchocolate poundage. Whether a product is considered chocolate or not is shown in the table (YES = chocolate, NO = not chocolate). • No one feeding product can make up more than 25% of the total pounds needed to create an acceptable feed mix. • There are two cereals (Chocolate Lucky Charms and Cap’n Crunch). Combined, they can be no more than 40% (in pounds) of the total mix required to meet the mix requirements. • Determine the optimal levels of the seven products to create your weekly feed plan that minimizes cost

Comment: You state criteria in your text, list them out line by line and set up calculations around them then control using the Solver and enter the constraints. There are simple examples on here - as well as some more complicated ones. One constraint is Product_x <= 0.25 * total_product

Comment: Posting the data as an image is poor as anyone who wants to help has to type your data. Post as text so people can copy and paste.

Comment: So what about missing info: daily limit and/or weekly limit? What is optimum based on? Protein requiremnt? Calcium requirement? or limts?

Answer (score 0):

So, threw this together, and made some assumptions but did not include minimum constraints on protein etc.
[image]

You can add control constraints for calcium etc as you wish - you can see how I have used the constraints already.